# How can I specify floating point precision in apache spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark

Is there a way to specify precision for floating point numbers in spark, preferably just before writing the RDD to file so that while calculation, precision is not lost?

Minimum working example,

```
    sqlCtxt = HiveContext(sc)

    fulldata = sqlCtxt.jsonFile(DATA_FILE)
    fulldata.registerTempTable("fulldata")

    newcpulists = sqlCtxt.sql('SELECT xxx FROM fulldata')


    def reduceSumPerc(x,y):
            #some reducefunction

    def mapfunc(x):
            #some map function

    reducedresult = newcpulists.map(mapfunc).reduceByKey(reduceSumPerc)

    # I want to reduce the precision just at this line, before writing to file.
    reducedresult.coalesce(1, True).saveAsTextFile(RESULT_PATH)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operation like this is not in a Spark scope. Since `saveAsTextFile` simply call `unicode` on non-unicode data, and `.encode` on `unicode` all you have to do is to format output strings manually using [standard Python formatting tools](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) For example:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([("foo", 0.123123132), ("bar", 0.00000001)])
rdd.map(lambda x: "{0}, {1:0.2f}".format(*x)).saveAsTextFile(...)
```

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the answer.. So, it there any suggestion on how to do this? Can I use some python's feature?

Comment: Just build an output string as in the provided snippet. Python formatting options should be more than enough.